# How to parse a .csv file and convert the addresses into Geolocations in Android

Tags: android, parsing, csv, geolocation

I have a .csv file containing addresses and other information. I would like to parse it and get only the addresses and the corresponding name, and then translate them into `Geolocation` co-ordinates to show on a Map.

How is this can be done?

Comment: Sounds like a one-off conversion, which probably means you should create some sort of batch job to do it. If you're going to use Java, have a look at using OpenCSV for parsing your csv content the easy way. Then supply the relevant data to i.e. the Google Geocoding API (2.500 reqs/day limit) and extract the geo coordinates from the response.

Answer (score 0):

You tagged this as android so I assume you are using java. Look at string's split method.

```
String aString = "Name,Location,Coordinates";
String valuesArray[] = aString.split(",");
//now valuesArray[0] = "Name", valuesArray[1] = "Location"...
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html